# Control Firebase timeout for disconnection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got an Android application which uses Firebase.

My records there got a field called "status" which is supposed to save the connectivity status to the server.

I got a `BroadcastReceiver` which identifies when the internet connection to the application is restored and then I update the status field myself and everything is fine in that direction.

I got a problem when the internet connection is lost. It seems to take a long time for Firebase to identify the connection is lost, and the status field is being updated after a long time. The update itself when disconnected is done like this:

```
child.child("status").onDisconnect().setValue(ClientStatus.OFFLINE);
```

This works, but like I said it takes a long time until the `onDisconnect()` method is actually invoked.

Is there a way to control the timeout for firebase until it decides the connection is lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to influence the timeout behavior neither in the client SDKs, nor on the Console.

Comment: This answer also got an approval from Firebase's support team

Comment: It's been 6 years now, has Firebase added a way to resolve this?

Comment: They haven't, as far as I know. RTDB hasn't seen many feature improvements, and Firestore categorically doesn't support this kind of presence.